# Android, XAMARIN: "cannot call this method while recyclerview is computing a layout or scrolling" on certain phones

Tags: android, xamarin.android

the above error:

"cannot call this method while `recyclerview` is computing a layout or scrolling"

only appears on my **Samsung s8**. My **s6** or **s4** will not give this error. The lines of code are those:

```
        var onScrollListener = new XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager);
        onScrollListener.LoadMoreEvent += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            int oldCount = loadPhotos.pictures.Count;
            loadPhotos.LoadMoreItems(Constants.LOADNEXTITEMSTHRESHHOLD);
            mAdapter.NotifyItemRangeChanged(oldCount - 1, loadPhotos.pictures.Count);
        };
```

and the error gets thrown at:

```
            mAdapter.NotifyItemRangeChanged(oldCount - 1, loadPhotos.pictures.Count);
```

Interessting on my **s8** is, that it has a larger screen compared to the other phones. My s6 and my **s4** both have a **16:9** ratio, while the **s8** has a 21.5:9 ratio. So I am guessing, this is what causes this issue. But can you help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is LoadMoreItems asyncronous? I think you should only notifyChanges when items are added to the adapter collection.

Comment: how would i find out whether its downloading items or not?